# What is the definition of the Euler characteristic of a stack?

Tags: algebraic-geometry

I've heard people talk about the Euler characteristic of a stack, and I understand that it is sometimes fractional. This tells me that it is not defined in any usual sense like $\sum (-1)^i\dim H^i(X)$. What is the definition? What are good references for this? What is the inspiration for the definition?

Comment: Stacks are closely related to orbifolds, and orbifolds have a definition of Euler characteristic.  I think one of the key motivations for orbifold Euler characteristic is that it should be multiplicative under finite covering spaces.